# How do I calculate the lift force on an aileron?

Tags: aerodynamics, flight-controls, control-surfaces

How do I calculate the force of lift acting on an aileron with a deflection of 8° and a flight speed of 40km/h?

Comment: How big of an aileron? How big of a plane?  40 khm is just under 25 mph. On my Cessna Cardinal, which has ailerons on the outer third of the wing, that little aileron movement at that speed while just rolling 
 (takes 60-65 mph to get airborne) would have very little affect.

Answer (score 2):

Cessna Cardinal planform, I don't know how to put this in a comment
[image]